# ES6 for of - is iterable evaluated only once?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Consider a simple for of:

```
for (const elem of document.getElementsByTagName('*') {
  // do something with elem
}
```

does getElementsByTagName evaluated only once or on each iteration ?

thx!

Comment: only once otherwise it would loop forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's evaluated once to obtain an `iterable`, which it then uses to obtain an `iterator`. It reuses that iterator to grab all the values and pass them to your `for` block. It's very similar to doing the following with a generator function:

```
function* getIntegers(max) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

const iterator = getIntegers(15);

while (true) {
  const { done, value } = iterator.next();
  if (done) {
    break;
  }

  console.log(value);
}
```

As noted by **loganfsmyth**, generator functions return an iterator directly. *Note: generator functions can also be used with the `for..of` construct*.

See [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) for more info.

Comment: Almost, it's evaluated to get an _iterable_ and then it gets the iterator from that. A generator function returns an iterator directly, and iterators are also iterables so they also work in this case.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I always get the terminology mixed up. Thanks for the clarification. :-)